# Sorting web sites in IIS

Tags: iis-6

Currently I'm running several websites that have several (branded) duplicates each, in the same IIS.
I wanted to have an easy overview of all the website groups so I used a naming convention like [siteName].[brandCode].
But lo and behold, IIS has its very own (seemingly random) way of ordering the entries in the "Web Sites" folder.

Any suggestions

(and yes, I use different application pools, but that's not what I'm aiming for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to edit the IIS Metabase to reorder those. I can't remember if theres a tool to do it in IIS6 but you can use [MetaEdit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240225/en-us) for IIS7 so that might be backwards compatible.

If not, the metabase is just an XML file so you can hand edit it (take a backup first) in notepad.

Comment: Messing with production environment metadata xml files.. that really sucks. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

as you are running IIS6, Install IIS6 Resource Toolkit and run Metabase Explorer, did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I always click on the "Web Sites" folder in IIS Manager and sort the list in the right panel by description.

I think there is no other option.